# Placing a UIDatePicker at the bottom of a TableViewController

Tags: ios, storyboard, uidatepicker

Is there any possibility directly in the storyboard to place the UIDatePicker at the bottom of the screen?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an outer view controller in which you would add the date picker view at the bottom and just above that add your table view controller's tableview.